# Cannot get just the text of an option from submitted data

Tags: webforms, tokens

I'm using Webform 8.x-5.8.

I've got a select box referencing some content. Of course, the numeric option value is passed. But when I reference submitted data with tokens, I just want to handle the plain text appearing with the options, but a concatenation of the text and the sequence " (NID)" is displayed instead, where NID is the content ID. An example with dummy code, names and values - just to roughly show what I suppose is happening behind - is following.

```
<select name="my_parameter">
<option value="80" selected>Some text</option>
...
...
...
</select>
```

By selecting *Some text*, "80" is passed.

My aim is displaying "Some text" picking it up from the submitted values.

Tried with `[webform_submission:values:my_parameter]` and `[webform_submission:values:my_parameter:value]`.
Anyway I get *Some text (80)*.

What am I supposed to do in order to get rid of that final NID in brackets?

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I scanned Webform's code base for `[webform_submission:values:` and eventually found the [webform.token.inc](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/8.x-5.19/webform.tokens.inc#L210-246) file to list a number of Webform tokens from submission values. One of them being `entity:*`. And another being `delta`.

```
'<li>element_key:entity:*</li>' .
'<li>element_key:delta:entity:*</li>'
```

> The 'entity:*' applies to the referenced entity
> The 'delta' is the numeric index for specific value

And when I scan Drupal core's code base for `:entity:title]` there's `[comment:entity:title]`. When I scan for just `:title]` there's `[node:title]` among the first hits. Okay, with all that I'd assume it must work with either:

```
[webform_submission:values:ELEMENT_KEY:entity:title]
```

Or if it's a multi-value field try it with a `:delta` of `0` to ensure you only get the first referenced node's title.

```
[webform_submission:values:ELEMENT_KEY:0:entity:title]
```

---

Just found out for taxonomy terms it's `:name` at the end:

```
[webform_submission:values:ELEMENT_KEY:entity:name]
```